# Auto Task Creation

Tags: process-builder, developer, visual-flows, sales-cloud

I have created Flows and Process builder process for renewal opportunities, where renewal opportunities are created 1 year from the close date of current opportunities.

Now business user requirement is, Renewal opportunities should also contain Tasks (and email alerts) based on time period. Task1 (120 days before close date), Task2 (90 days before close date), Task3 (60 days before close date), Task4 (30 days before close date).

here is the screenshot

[image: Renewal opportunities]

Despite this auto, tasks are not getting created. Any help is appreciated in this regard

Best Regards
Prashant

Comment: If you want to create task under renewal opportunity then develop another process builder to create tasks t run after renewal oppty creation. In this workflow, renewal oppty is still not created and you are trying to create task under that...Which does not make sense

Answer (score 2):

Just like @αΥβ commented, you cannot create the tasks and the renewal opportunity in the same process since the opportunity has not yet been committed in DB by the time your task creation rule runs.

The simplest approach would be to **create a process and a workflow rule**: the process would create a renewal opportunity and the workflow would create the tasks. The workflow rule would run upon the creation of the opportunity and create and assign a task to the designated user.

You can find the task creation for workflow rules under `Process Automation > Workflow Actions > Tasks`.

Nonetheless, there are many other possible solutions. You can also use two processes like @αΥβ suggested or even create a short Apex class with an annotated method `@InvocableMethod` which contains all the logic which you invoke from a process builder. Still though, I would recommend the first approach I suggested since it is by far the simplest one easiest to maintain.